# yaml damping a list as a string without quotes

Tags: python, list, yaml

I am trying to dump a list in a yaml file in python. However as a result I get quotes around my list.
Here is my code:

```
data = [679.0077123045467, 0.0, 356.3515350783442, 0.0, 672.9969017826554, 196.5430429125135,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
data = str(data)

my_dict = {"matrix": {'rows': 3, 'cols': 3, 'data': data}}
```

The result:

```
matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: '[679.0077123045467, 0.0, 356.3515350783442, 0.0, 672.9969017826554, 196.5430429125135,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0]'
```

The desired result:

```
matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [679.0077123045467, 0.0, 356.3515350783442, 0.0, 672.9969017826554, 196.5430429125135,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

How can I dump it without quotes?
Thank you.

Comment: What you want is *the opposite* of what you've done. You *explicitly* converted the list to a string, so yaml correctly has to quote it. Or else that would be a valid yaml list.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't do `data = str(data)`.

Yaml can represent a list with dashes. Don't worry though, if you load it back in Python it will be a normal list again!

Comment: But it gives something different like dashes(-) before list items and each one stays in newline.

`matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data:
  - 679.0077123045467
  - 0.0
  - 356.3515350783442
  - 0.0
  - 672.9969017826554
  - 196.5430429125135
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0`

Comment: @Reactionic yes.. *that's yaml*

Comment: @Reactionic if you are trying to force using the `[ ...]` list format in YAML, there may be options depending on the library you are using. for pyaml, I think `yaml.dump(a, default_flow_style=False)` may work, (of course, omitting `data = str(data)`

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, yaml can represent a list with dashes. Don't worry though, if you load it back in Python it will be a normal list again!

Comment: Thank you and @juanpa.arrivillaga . The problem is the application which read this yaml file. According to sample yaml file, there is not quotes around square brackets. Anyway I solved it reading yaml file after writing and deleting quotes.

Comment: @Reactionic *don't do that*. Just leave out `data = str(data)` and leave it with the dashes format. *If the application uses yaml then it understands that as equivalent to what you are doing by hand*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga For me, `default_flow_style=False` adds dashes, while **passing no arguments** uses [] syntax as desired. (Python 3.6.9, PyYAML 3.12) :)